# Alert View directs to an empty view controller without buttons

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uialertview

I'm trying to make an alert view so that upon selecting "Yes" (one of the buttons in AlertView), the user is directed to a new view controller with a button which I made via Storyboard.  My code for the IBAction is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)alertButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome Back to SymTrack!" message:@"Did you have reoccuring symptoms?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

This is the code for the clickedButtonAtIndex which gives me the empty view controller without the button:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    { 
        UpdateViewController *updateVC = [[UpdateViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:updateVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I've also tried these other codes for clickedButtonAtIndex but I got NSException for all of them:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        UpdateViewController *updateVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UpdateViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:updateVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

or

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        UpdateViewController *updateVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UpdateViewController"];
        UINavigationController *alertNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:updateVC];
        [self presentViewController:updateVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

note: all this code is within the view controller with the button that upon clicking brings the alert view up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know your UpdateViewController is not being presented. Also if you are using storyboards, you should instantiate your vc with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method(like the last one)

Comment: It seems like your `UpdateViewController` in storyboard doesn't have the same identifier you are providing in this method.

Comment: I believe my UpdateViewController is being presented just not correctly.  In my UpdateViewController.h in view controller method i used: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; and the blue screen is being displayed after selecting the alertView but not the button on the view.

Comment: What happens when you present the view controller using the last approach you mentioned?

Comment: I get a NSException: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: What does it say, post the error at least. Did you check that your view controller in the storyboard has the exact identifier?

Comment: after the error it crashes there, is that what you're asking? yes the view controller has the exact same identifier

Comment: I mean the log in the console window. What does it say?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x8c3cfa0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'UpdateViewController''

Comment: I checked though and recreated a new view and named the custom class as UpdateViewController so there anything else that I would be missing?

Comment: OK so in the storyboard for the UpdateViewController I went to Identity > Storyboard ID and updated the name UpdateViewController. Now the alert button directs the user back to the same screen instead of the UpdateViewController. the app doesn't crash and does call the code for the last snippet of code but is the same screen

Comment: I went back and recreated the storyboard with the identifier and it worked! Thanks so much for all you help :)